# what if the ethereum accounts balance value low than per eth.sendTransaction gas cost, Can the little ether transfer to another account?

Tags: account, ethereum

What if the ethereum accounts balance value low than per `eth.sendTransaction` gas cost, Can the little ether transfer to another account?

Can the gas cost default account pointer to another?

> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[1], to: eth.accounts[2], value:50000000000000})  //the value low the gas cost 21000
>   I0318 00:24:21.360815 internal/ethapi/api.go:1143] Tx(0x33b58084a35e99245b9c931204a0d161b9d00f9fae5ffb307aff29f200e5cd30) to: 0x49fbd70ca9f90972806c375a111d08950d203f96
>   "0x33b58084a35e99245b9c931204a0d161b9d00f9fae5ffb307aff29f200e5cd30"

what if `eth.getBalance(eth.account[1]) < gas cost 21000`, can the execution be successful ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, if you don't have enough ether to make a successful transaction, the transaction will fail. You always need enough Ether to fund your transactions.

Having less than the required gas cost value will result in your small Ether amount not being able to be moved until the cost to move the Ether is small enough for you to afford.